# getting frequency of audio on every interval of time in android

Tags: audio, frequency

I am using Media Recorder class to record sound . and I am getting amplitude on some interval of time and converting it into decibel, but what I want I also want to get frequency of audio on that interval with corresponding to that amplitude or decibel. I searched, but I did not get proper idea that how to do it.
please if someone can guide me then please help

Answer (score 0):

The process most often used to determine pitch is called the "fast fourier transform". Try using those keywords or the common abbreviation "FFT" along with the language or platform you are working on and that should bring up libraries to incorporate that can do this. Coding an FFT is pretty complex, so you'll probably want to use a library. But if you are curious about the math and how they work, check out [The Scientists and Engineers Guide to Digital Signal Processing](http://www.dspguide.com/).